# Setting a subsection or slice of a global numpy array through a python object

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy

I am trying to reference a slice of a "global" numpy array via a object attribute. Here is what I think the class structure would be like and it's use case.

```
import numpy

class X:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.pid = [0, 1, 2]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'values':
            return self.parent.P[self.pid]
        else:
            raise AttributeError


class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.P = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        self._values = X(self)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'x':
            return self._values.values
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

Here is the use case:

```
>>> n = Node()
>>> print n.P
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
>>> print n.x
[1 2 3]
>>> print n.x[1:3]
[2 3]
```

Which works fine, now I would like to assign values to `n.P` through the `n.x` attribute by,

```
>>> n.x = numpy.array([11, 12, 13])
```

to get,

```
>>> print n.P
[ 11  12  13  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

Or assign values to slices by,

```
>>> n.x[1:3] = numpy.array([77, 88])
```

to get,

```
>>> print n.P
[ 11  77  88  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

But for the life of me, I'm struggling to get this assignment working. I thought it would be easy using `__setattr__` and `__setitem__`, but a whole day later I still haven't managed it.

Ultimately, `n.x` will be returned as a multi-dimensional array where the `X` class will reshape is on return, but is stored in a `n.P` which is a vector. I have removed this to simplify the problem.

I would love some help on this. Has anyone done this before? Or suggest how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**SOLUTION**

So after many days of stumbling around I found a solution. I suspect this can be simplified and refined. The solution is to create a X object in your Node object. When it's retrieved, it returns temporary numpy object (Values) with knowledge of it's parent node and pids. The *setslice*_ function is defined in this update the global P array with the new values. If the X object is is assigned, it doesn't return a Values object but sets the global P values directly.

Two points, which may be invalid: 1. The Node and X objects had to be a sub-class of *object*; 2. if setting a higher dimension array, you need to use `__setitem__` instead, which won't work on 1D arrays or lists.

As I said I suspect this code can be improves since I'm not sure I fully understand it. I am happy to take improvements and suggestions.

Thanks for your help, especially Bago.

Here is my final code.

```
import numpy

class Values(numpy.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, node, pids):
        obj = numpy.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.node = node
        obj.pids = pids
        return obj

    def __setslice__(self, i, j, values):
        self.node._set_values(self.pids[i:j], values)


class X(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        p = instance.P[instance.pids]
        return Values(p, instance, instance.pids)

    def __set__(self, instance, values):
        instance.P[instance.pids] = values

class Node(object):

    x = X()

    def __init__(self, pids=[0, 1, 2]):
        self.P = numpy.arange(11)
        self.pids = pids

    def _set_values(self, pids, values):
        self.P[pids] = values


node = Node(pids=[4, 5, 6, 7])
print '\nInitial State:'
print 'P =', node.P
print 'x =', node.x
print 'x[1:3] =', node.x[1:3]

print '\nSetting node.x = [44, 55, 66, 77]:'
node.x = [44, 55, 66, 77]
print 'P =', node.P
print 'x =', node.x
print 'x[1:3] =', node.x[1:3]

print '\nSetting node.x[1:3] = [100, 200]:'
node.x[1:3] = [100, 200]
print 'P =', node.P
print 'x =', node.x
print 'x[1:3] =', node.x[1:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what's not working, but I think maybe you're trying to do something like this:

```
import numpy

class X(object):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.pid = [0, 1, 2]

    @property
    def values(self):
        tmp = self.parent.P[self.pid]
        return tmp
    @values.setter
    def values(self, input):
        self.parent.P[self.pid] = input

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.P = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        self._values = X(self)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._values.values
    @x.setter
    def x(self, input):
        self._values.values = input
```

I hope that get's you started.

update

The reason that `n.x[1:3] = [77, 88]` doesn't work using this approach is because `n.x` and `n.x[:] = ~` both call the get method of X.values which returns `tmp`. But `tmp` is a copy of part of P and after `n.x[:] = ~` `tmp` is thrown away and `P` is not updated. `tmp` is a copy because when you index an array with another array you get a copy not a view. Here is an example to make that more clear, you can read more about numpy slicing/indexing [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
>>> P = np.arange(10)
>>> pid = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> Q = P[pid]
>>> Q[:] = 99
>>> P
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> R = P[1:4]
>>> R[:] = 99
>>> P
array([ 0, 99, 99, 99,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
>>> P[[1,2]][:] = 88
>>> P
array([ 0, 99, 99, 99,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

setitem won't help, because you're calling the setitem method of the `tmp` not `X`.

The easiest way to make it work is to replace the pid array with a slice, but I know that's kind of limiting. You could also keep track of the `tmp` array, have a self._tmp so you can move the values from _tmp to P later. I know neither of those are perfect, but maybe someone else here will come up with a better approach. Sorry I couldn't do more.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It mostly works but I cannot do n.x[1:3] = numpy.array([77, 88]) and get n.P = numpy.array([1, 77, 88, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]). I've looked everywhere for @values.setitem decorator but no luck.

Comment: Thanks Bago. That's what I thought. I started searching for ways to pass pointers for a slice instead of the copy. My first implementation was to store values in X which I later added to P by manually running a function but I'm wanting to do away with it. I might have to update slices using a function for the meantime, i.e., n.set_values(slice, values). I'm thinking about a additional dummy object that detects setitem vs setattr, then values to X as function calls. Not sure if it'll work, I can't quite get my head around it. Thanks anyway.